# Contains where syntax different when placed in own method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, contains

I am trying to refactor some code out of one method into its own method but the compiler is complaining.

This code works fine inside a longer method

```
let aboutLocation = self.locationWords.contains(where: {$0.caseInsensitiveCompare((newmessage)!) == .orderedSame})

if (aboutLocation) {
    self.startLocationServices()
}
```

When I try to place the code in its own method as follows it gives error message: Extraneous argument label 'where' in call and suggests I delete the word.

```
func startLocationServicesIfLocation(newmessage:String){
    let aboutLocation = self.locationWords.contains(where: {$0.caseInsensitiveCompare((newmessage)!) == .orderedSame})

    if (aboutLocation) {
        self.startLocationServices()
    }
}
```

Why would it be different inside one method compared with the other

Comment: For one, you're trying to force unwrap (which is usually a bad thing, in itself), `newmessage`, which isn't even an Optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is misleading.

In the function the parameter `newmessage` is non-optional so you have to remove the exclamation mark (and the enclosing parentheses – also around the `if` condition – anyway).

```
let aboutLocation = self.locationWords.contains(where: {$0.caseInsensitiveCompare(newmessage) == .orderedSame})
if aboutLocation { ...
```

But you can indeed omit the `where` parameter label using trailing closure syntax

```
let aboutLocation = locationWords.contains{ $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(newmessage) == .orderedSame }
```

Comment: When I call this function, I am starting with an unwrapped variable.  Should I condition calling the function on there being a value for the variable?

Comment: If `newmessage` could be safely force unwrapped the declaration of the function is fine. Otherwise declare the `newmessage` parameter as `String?` and add a `guard` line

Comment: The Swift compiler's error messages are usually awful. You have to remember to translate whatever the compiler says to "Derp? Something is wrong. You figure it out." In some ways that would better, since often the error message you get is very specific, very technical, and completely wrong.